# Best way for handling 150k records import from Excel to Oracle Database using Apache Poi API

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, apache-poi

We have to improve the performance of one excel upload function developed in java using POI API. At present this code piece takes 40 minutes for completing the upload process for excel containing 1000 records. One requirement is coming for uploading the excel sheet which contains 150k records. So we will plan to revamp the code and decide to use stream API for getting the content form excel.

We are doing basic validations and trying to insert these data into six tables in the database. After inserting the amount of data we need to fetch this data for a scheduled job which is intended to update the above-mentioned tables fields based on some regulatory data comparison. Our application using spring and hibernate for transaction management.

1. What is the best way to use the transaction management for uploading/fetching of this volume of data?
2. Does the batch update concept will cause any table lock scenario?

Comment: Guessing you meant 150k (1.5 lakh), not 1.5 million. Also, please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: @James, That is called Units (metric) system “not” words and that is British. Indian metric system is totally different and unique.

Comment: @AjayKumar You're saying "lakh" is British? That's not true at all.

Comment: Not sure about the origin of Lakh but 100k is called Laksh in original Indian number system. Lets not go into these details here lol.! Lets focus on tech discussion. :-)